# Metalinear frame bundle on sphere or $\mathbb{C}P^n$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, dg.differential-geometry, mp.mathematical-physics, sg.symplectic-geometry, spin-geometry

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold. A complex metalinear frame bundle $\tilde F(P)\to M$ of a rank $n$ complex vector bundle $P\to M$ is a principal $ML(n,\mathbb{C})$-bundle together with a covering map $f:\tilde F(P)\to F(P)$ and $r:ML(n,\mathbb{C})\to GL(n,\mathbb{C})$which makes the diagram

\begin{array}{lll}
  \tilde F(P)\times ML(n,\mathbb{C}) & \rightarrow &\tilde F(P)\\
  (f,r)\downarrow && \downarrow f\\
   F(P)\times GL(n,\mathbb{C})  & \rightarrow & F(P)
 \end{array}
commutes. The horizontal arrows are natural group actions and here $ML(n,\mathbb{C})$ is the metalinear group $\frac{\mathbb{C}\times SL(n,\mathbb{C})}{2\mathbb{Z}}$. We call this complex metalinear frame bundle a complex metalinear structure on $P$.

> My question is when $M=\mathbb{C}P^n$,  $M=\mathbb{C}P^{\infty}$  or $M=S^n$, what is the complex
>   metalinear structure?

Comment: What do you want the complex vector bundle $P$ to be for your three spaces? And, given such a $P$, is there not often a choice of such structure?

Comment: A suitable complex vector bundle $P$ for my three spaces, and also the choice of metalinear structure is are parametrized by $H^1(M,\mathbb{Z}_2)$.